# Div behaving like a link to index.html

Tags: html, css

So, what I am trying to do is divide the page (of width 700 pixels) in 60:40 ratio. In the 40 I want a pic, and the rest 60 text. I have used div to wrap both image and the text. But, the problem is that whenever I hover the cursor on the block, it acts as link to the index.html. I mean I want text selection over the text not hand cursor as default.

Here's the CSS, I am using:

```
#image {
width: 40%;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 50px;
float: left;
}

#contentwrap {
width: 60%;
float: left;
text-align: justify;
font-size: 18px;
height: 225px;
}

#contentwrap p {font-family: arial, helvetica;}
#contentwrap pre {
margin-top: 45px;
text-align: center;
}
```

The structure of html is as follows:

```
<div id = "image"><img src = "asd.jpg"></div>
<div id = "contentwrap"><pre> *text* </pre>
<p> *text*</p> </div>
```

Image is 175x175 px

Comment: Please, create a JSFiddle to demonstrate this issue.

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be happening unless there is, indeed, a link OR you explicitly set `cursor: pointer` in your css. Try setting `cursor: auto !important`.